# c# stdin read not responding

Tags: c#, stream, console-application, stdout, stdin

I have a program that listens to the console stdin stream.

- When `Read()` returns, every character is read out one by one and passed to `method()`.
- `method()` then appends the character to a `StringBuilder`.
- If the character is `'\n'` , then `method()` calls `respond()`, which prints out the read characters and clears the `StringBuilder`.

However, even after typing something in the console and pressing Enter, I have to press/move my mouse, the mouse buttons, or the keyboard within the focus of the console for the text typed to be echoed. Even more mysterious is that when I set a breakpoint in the first curly brace of `Main()` and step into every single statement thereafter, the program executes correctly. How can i fix this? Thanks a lot!

```
public class test
{
    static byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
    static Stream instrm = Console.OpenStandardInput();
    static Stream outstrm = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
    static System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            instrm.Read(buffer, 0, 1);
            method(buffer);
        }
    }
    public static void method(byte[] buffer)
    {
        sb.Append(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
        if (buffer[0] == (byte)10) respond();
    }
    public static void respond()
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
        outstrm.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        outstrm.Flush();
        sb.Clear();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I just tested and found out that it had nothing to do with the thread, so took the part away. I originally posted it so as it was a problem in my other program, this being only a test model to demonstrate it.

Comment: Is it intentional to let your Main method end ?

Comment: Please add puctuation, capital letters and whitespace to your text so I can decipher it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman does rather defeat the point of multi-threading.

Comment: sorry, just tested it further, editing my question.

Comment: Try showing a message box in your respond method. Also maybe closing your output stream might help.

Comment: Note that you have at least two problems here: 1. Stream.Read has a return value. Use it. 2. You cannot process UTF-8 byte by byte like here. Non-ASCII characters use more than one byte, and you cannot process them piecewise using just GetString. Also note that generally, console input is line-buffered, you want get single characters in “real time”.

Comment: both of these problems dont affect me.
1. my buffer is only of length. my call to read tells read to give me 1 byte. so the return value is useless to me, since i always get one byte.
2. i AM processing only ascii characters. im only using utf8 because of microsoft's suggestion on msdn. also, i do NOT wnat to get the characters real time. i want them as they are in the stream.
thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would change the program like this:

```
static byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
static TextReader instrm = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput());
static TextWriter outstrm = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
static void Main()
{
  while (true)
  {
    var readLine = instrm.ReadLine();
    respond(readLine);
  }
}

public static void respond(string line)
{
  outstrm.Write(line);
  outstrm.Flush();
}
```

It is easier and works. The main difference is to use `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` instead for `Stream`.

Comment: how could i have forgotten about those classes? thanks! still, i dont get whats wrong with my program.

Comment: since the readline() ends with either "\r\n", "\n", or "\r", although it doesnt affect my program that much, i decided to try out streamreader's read(), and it works perfectly. so im certain the problem lies in MS's bad implementation of stream's read().